# Intersection of span

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ be vectors of a vector space.

If $\operatorname{span}\langle a_i\rangle \cap\operatorname{span}\langle a_j\rangle = \overline 0 $ for all $i\ne j$.

Does $\operatorname{span}\langle a_1,a_2,a_3\rangle \cap\operatorname{span}\langle a_2,a_3,a_4\rangle  = \operatorname{span}\langle a_2,a_3\rangle$?

Is this really true or how do I prove that it's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No! this is false, For example in $\Bbb{R}^3$, take $$a_1=(1,0,0), a_2=(0,1,0),a_3=(0,0,1),a_4=(1,1,1)$$

$\text{span}\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}=\Bbb{R}^3=\text{span}\{a_2,a_3,a_4\} \neq \text{span}\{a_2,a_3\}$

Comment: Oh wow such a easy prove that I didn't see... Thank you a lot how did I miss that :p!!